# Matrixmultiplication with a vector?

Tags: python, matrix, vector

I want to transform a vector with 10 rows and 1 column to 10 columns and 1 row to multiply it with a scalar and get a scalar out of it like a matrix-multiplication. I want to do this in python.

Comment: In what universe you can get a scalar by multiplying a `10x1` and a scalar?

Comment: So I want to multiply every number in row with the scalar and add it like a matrix-mulitplication

Comment: what's wrong with `sum(yourMatrix*yourScalar)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a numpy array, you can do what sagi mentioned in the comments. You can take the sum of the vector times the scalar. Here is an example code:

```
vector = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
scalar = 2

total = sum(vector * scalar)
```